# python MessageBoxA is behind cmd window

Tags: python, python-2.7, messagebox

I have a python2.7 program that converts text reports into Excel spreadsheets.

It is run by dragging and dropping the file into a desktop icon.

a Windows CMD window opens while the program is running.

When the program is finished I display a windows message box:

```
windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None,"Finished","gen2xls",0)
```

The message box appears on the screen but instantly moves behind the CMD window so you can't see it.

It seems like the focus changes to the CMD window as soon as the message box appears on the screen.

Is there a way to keep the focus on the message box until it is clicked?

If you look in the code below, there is a test to see if the file is one of two types. If the file is not one of the two types then there is a print statement 'print 'file does not appear to be a gencount'' followed by a continue statement. If this is triggered then the 'finished' box appears in front of the CMD screen, but when the job runs to completion the focus is changed to the CMD window as soon as the message box appears.

The main bit of code is below:

```
def runexcel(args):
    sheets = []
    """Convert LSC gencount to Excel file
    """
    sawerror = False
    print "Running gen2xls"
    if len(args) == 1:
        windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None,"Error: Please drag at least one file","gen2xls",0)
        sys.exit(1)
    try: 
        for fname in args[1:]:
            file = open(fname,"r")
            get_type = get_gen_type(file) 
            if get_type == -1:
                print 'file does not appear to be a gencount'
                continue  #skip file if not a gencount (only tests for presence of pagefeed char)
            if get_type[0] == 'laur':
                sheets =  get_l_sheets(file)  #LAURA'S FORMAT:
            else:
                if get_type[0] == 'serg':
                    sheets = get_s_sheets(file,get_type[1],get_type[2])  #SERGEI'S FORMAT:
            make_sheets(sheets,fname)
            print "Finished Processing %s" % fname
        windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None,"Finished","gen2xls",0)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print "Errors occurred, please check the above messages"
        windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None,"Error: Problems occurred, please check them and try again","gen2xls",0)
##########################################################################################
##########################################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runexcel(sys.argv)
```